# How do you assemble, link and run a .s file in linux?

Tags: linux, assembly, compilation, intel

I'm getting a weird error message when trying to assemble and run a .s file using AT&T Intel Syntax. Not sure if I'm even using the correct architecture to begin with, or if I'm having syntax errors, if I'm not using the correct commands to assemble and link, etc. Completely lost and I do not know where to begin.

So basically, I have a file called yea.s , which contains some simple assembler instructions. I then try to compile it using the command `as yea.s -o yea.o` and then link is using `ld yea.o -o yea`. When running ld, I get this weird message:`ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol _start; defaulting to 000000440000`.

This is the program im trying to run, very simple and doesn't really do anything.

```
resMsg: .asciz "xxxxxxxx"

.text
.global main
main:
pushq $0
ret
```

I just cannot figure out what's going on. Obviously, this is for school homework. I'm not looking for the answer to the homework, obviously, but this is the starting point to where I can actually start the coding. And I just cant figure out how to simple run the program, which it doesn't say in the assignment. Anyway, thanks in advance guys!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Linux executables require an entry point to be specified.  The entry point is the address of the first instruction to be executed in your program.  If not specified otherwise, the link editor looks for a symbol named `_start` to use as an entry point.  Your program does not contain such a symbol, thus the linker complains and picks the beginning of the `.text` section as the entry point.  To fix this problem, rename `main` to `_start`.

Note further that unlike on DOS, there is nothing to return to from `_start`.  So your attempt to return is going to cause a crash.  Instead, call the system call `sys_exit` to exit the program:

```
mov $0, %edi  # exit status
mov $60, %eax # system call number
syscall       # perform exit call
```

Alternatively, if you want to use the C runtime environment and call functions from the C library, leave your program as is and instead assemble and link using the C compiler driver `cc`:

```
cc -o yea yea.s
```

If you do so, the C runtime environment provides the entry point for you and eventually tries to call a function `main` which is where your code comes in.  This approach is required if you want to call functions from the C library.  If you do it this way, make sure that `main` follows the SysV ABI (calling convention).

Note that even then your code is incorrect.  The return value of a function is given in the `eax` (resp. `rax`) register and not pushed on the stack.  To return zero from `main`, write

```
mov $0, %eax   # exit status
ret            # return from function
```

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot! Yeah, actually the assignment is about writing a assembler routines that can be used in a C program. Gonna try this, appreciate it a lot!

Comment: @lunarkakka Thanks.  Also note that there is no “AT&T Intel syntax.” There is AT&T syntax (which is what UNIX `as` uses) and Intel syntax (which is what many other assemblers use).  Make sure you always use precise and correct terms for the things you are talking about or others are going to be very confused.

Comment: `cannot find entry symbol _start; defaulting to 000000440000` is not an error, just an `ld` *warning*.  If there's no exported/global `_start` symbol, `ld` defaults to using the start of the `.text` section as the entry point.  This works fine for one-off / toy experiments like sticking a couple instruction in a file so you can single-step them with GDB.  The OP's code presumably assembles + links, and if run then segfaults on code fetch after the `ret` to absolute address `0`.  Your answer is correct re: what they should actually do, though: build with a C compiler that will call main.

Answer (score -3):

In all currently supported versions of Ubuntu open the terminal and type:

sudo apt install as31 nasm
as31: Intel 8031/8051 assembler
This is a fast, simple, easy to use Intel 8031/8051 assembler.

nasm: General-purpose x86 assembler
Netwide Assembler. NASM will currently output flat-form binary files, a.out, COFF and ELF Unix object files, and Microsoft 16-bit DOS and Win32 object files.

If you are using NASM in Ubuntu 18.04, the commands to compile and run an .asm file named example.asm are:

nasm -f elf64 example.asm # assemble the program
ld -s -o example example.o # link the object file nasm produced into an executable file
./example # example is an executable file

Comment: Why have them install `as31`?

Comment: That is not the assembler OP wants.